# codeigniter rewrite url get method(url friendly)

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

i am trying to rewrite the codeigniter url when using the get method.
I programmed a search engine for my project(a shop) which works fine, but is not very url friendly.
The current url is:

```
shopping/search?query=cat
```

Shopping is the controller, search is the method and query is the get parameter that been searched, in this example it's cat.

What i want to change is to make the url to appear like this:

```
shopping/search/cat
```

I have been trying to do it with the .htaccess in many ways, but it didn't worked. Here is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# Send request via index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you only looking for a `.htaccess` solution? can't you modify the search method to look for the query string in the url instead of `$_GET`? should be as simple as `function search($query){...}`

Comment: I am not using the $_GET i am using the codeigniter get input. Can you show me an example of how i can "catch" the search input without the get method? because if i have a search form i have to send it through either post or get.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/shopping/search/?$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^query=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule . /shopping/search/%1? [R=302,L]

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
# Send request via index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Replace with below if you want a permanent redirect :

```
RewriteRule . /shopping/search/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I have tried to add it at the end of my .htaccess file, but it didn't made any changes at all.

Comment: Just edited the answer. Added RewriteEngine On at the top. Try this. If it still doesn't work then put the code on the top of the file. Hope you are making changes to the root .htaccess file.

Comment: It's still the same.. and don't worry i have already checked 3 times and this is my root .htaccess of the project.

Comment: Hey @user3460046, just modified the answer above, had some bugs. Please try this one, this should work. Tested on my local machine.

Comment: Hey ankitsnghn, thank your for your help but it's still not working. i have tried to put it before my original, .htaccess, after and many more ways but it's not working. Can you show me the code that works in your local machine? maybe there is something else i need to change in order for it to work? and here is one of the examples of how i tried to write it:http://pastebin.com/u2LgH7nd

Comment: Hey @user3460046, it works fine if you remove the bottom section rules `Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
# Send request via index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`
Just checked my CI installation and it doesn't come with an `htaccess` at the root. What's the reason for having them ?

Comment: Latest working code has been updated and this is working perfectly fine. Dropbox link to working CI installation : https://www.dropbox.com/s/oppaw0tuj17mrxh/codeigniter.zip